# React set initial state from parent and updates in child should propagate to parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How should the case be handled when a child component needs to derive its initial state from the parent, but user can also change value of the state in the child and this needs to be propagated back up to the parent?

Simplified example:

```
const Child = (props) => {
  const { parentProperty, dispatch } = props;
  const [localValue, setLocalValue] = useState(parentProperty); //this line only gets called in the initial render.

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalValue(parentProperty); //doesn't this cause circular loop? parent->child->parent?
  }, [parentProperty]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "CHILD_PROP_CHANGE", localValue }); //need to propagate localValue user change back to parent
  }, [localValue]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={localValue}
        onChange={(e) => setLocalValue(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You can try calling useState in the parent component and pass setVariable as a prop to the child component and update state as and when required from both, parent as well as the child component. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To sync state between parent and child components in React, you can lift the state up to the parent and pass it down to the child as a prop. A prop is a way to give data to another component. You can also give a function as a prop, so the child can use it to send data back to the parent. This lets the parent manage the state and the child show and change it.

For example:

```
const Child = ({ value, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={value} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState("")

  const handleChangeValue = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <Child value={value} onChange={handleChangeValue} />
  )
}
```

To learn more, please see [sharing state between component](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components).